# How to use switch toggle conditionally in render function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, material-ui

I'm new to React JS. I have two objects taskData and taskDatafilter. I want to render two of them  based on condition. The toggle switch if the switch is turned on then only render taskDatafilter but if it is off then rendered taskData.
My code so far is

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "reactstrap/lib/Button";
import TodoItem from "../TodoItem/TodoItem";
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

export default class TodoList extends Component {

    render() {
    const {
      showTaskData,
      clearList,
      handleDelete,
      todoDeleteMsg,
      editTodo,
    } = this.props;
    const isActive = this.props.showTaskData.active;
    let taskData = [];
      let taskDatafilter = [];
    if (showTaskData.length) {
      taskData = showTaskData.map((task) => {
        return (
          <TodoItem
            key={task.id}
            title={task.title}
            description={task.description}
            handleDelete={() => {
              handleDelete(task.id);
            }}
            todoDeleteMsg={todoDeleteMsg}
            editTodo={() => {
              editTodo(task.id, task.title, task.description);
            }}
          />
        );
      });
        taskDatafilter = showTaskData.filter((value)=> value.completed === 1).map((task) => {
            return (
                <TodoItem
                    key={task.id}
                    title={task.title}
                    description={task.description}
                    handleDelete={() => {
                        handleDelete(task.id);
                    }}
                    todoDeleteMsg={todoDeleteMsg}
                    editTodo={() => {
                        editTodo(task.id, task.title, task.description);
                    }}
                />
            );
        });
    }
    return (
      <ul className="list-group my-2">
        <h3 className="text-capitalize">Todo List </h3>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between mb-5">
          Task and Description
            <Switch value="on" inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Switch A' }}  />{taskDatafilter}
        </div>
        {taskData}
        <Button color="danger" onClick={clearList}>
          Clear all
        </Button>
        <p className="text-danger">{todoDeleteMsg}</p>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

I am confused to use the switch button with that condition in my code I am badly stuck at this point for 5 hours. Basically I am working on todo app and I want to show a switch button on the front end which if on then show completed task else show active tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bound your list items into parent tag like div or React.Fragment

```
if (showTaskData.length) {
      taskData = return( <div> {showTaskData.map((task) => 
          <TodoItem
            key={task.id}
            title={task.title}
            description={task.description}
            handleDelete={() => {
              handleDelete(task.id);
            }}
            todoDeleteMsg={todoDeleteMsg}
            editTodo={() => {
              editTodo(task.id, task.title, task.description);
            }}
          />
      )} </div> );
        taskDatafilter =return( <div> {
           showTaskData.filter((value)=> value.completed === 1).map((task) =>
                <TodoItem
                    key={task.id}
                    title={task.title}
                    description={task.description}
                    handleDelete={() => {
                        handleDelete(task.id);
                    }}
                    todoDeleteMsg={todoDeleteMsg}
                    editTodo={() => {
                        editTodo(task.id, task.title, task.description);
                    }}
                />
        ))
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to add ternary condition in your jsx like this

In you constructor define you variable

```
 constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        showDataFilter: true,
      }
```

And in you jsx use this variable in ternary operator like this

```
render(
  ...
  {(this.state.showDataFilter)?
     <taskDatafilter/>
    :
     <taskData/>
  }
)
```

Comment: <Switch value="on" onChange={(event) => (event.target.value === 'on')? 
this.setState({showDataFilter:true}):this.setState({showDataFilter:false}) } /> 

{(this.state.showDataFilter)?<taskDatafilter/> : <taskData/>}

Comment: just add showDataFilter variable in constructor and onChange event on switch

Comment: And remove html tag from taskDatafilter and taskData like this............
 {(this.state.showDataFilter)?
     taskDatafilter
    :
     taskData
  }

Comment: Also I notice mistake in your code ... see my answer below

Comment: when I click switch button its value changes one time lets say instead of true i intiliazed it with false in the constructor like constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        showDataFilter: false,
      } and now when I click on the toggle switch button to turn it on its state is getting changed to true and I can see only completed record but when I again click on toggle switch nothing is happening like it is not going back to false condition and it runs only once nut running back and forth alternatively to true or false